# Replacing SQL CASE with multiple Scopes in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I'm trying to create a query to count records that have a common identifier but appear twice with different attributes on my site - i.e. someone with a certain IP address creates an `Impression` with the name 'view' and subsequently creates one with the name 'conv' (I have a tracking pixel and want to count view-through conversions).

At the moment, I find conversions using the Rails query below, which I converted from SQL:

```
@impressions = Impression.select(:ip_address).group(:ip_address).having
("COUNT(CASE WHEN name = 'view' THEN 1 END) > 0 AND 
COUNT(CASE WHEN name = 'conv' THEN 1 END) > 0")
```

Is there a cleaner way to do this in Rails? My initial thought is that using multiple scopes might be the best way:

```
def self.converted(ip_address)
  where("name == 'conv' and ip_address == ?", ip_address)
end

def self.viewed(ip_address)
  where("name == 'view' and ip_address == ?", ip_address)
end
```

Controller (no idea how this should look...):

```
scope :view_through_conversion, Impression.viewed & Impression.converted

...

@impressions = Impression.all.view_through_conversion(ip_address)
```

But I don't have any experience with scope and I don't know if this offers many advantages over my way. Can anyone provide some guidance on the best way to achieve this in Rails?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A cleaner way in SQL, if I understand your intent correctly, might be:

```
@impressions = Impression.select(:ip_address).
                          where(:name => ["view", "conv"]).
                          group(:ip_address).
                          having("count(distinct name) > ?",1)
```